# How to open 2 windows in visual studio code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

How to open a code window and display window as below:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need to use Sandbox. This link should explain in more detail.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jccr.sandbox

Answer (score 0):

It look like [Live server](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer) VScode extension.